# HTML how to make users type in bold or italic?

Tags: javascript, html, wysiwyg

The problem is: I am developing a simple text editor with a bold and italic button. I have seen a ton of tutorials, which alter the selection of text. In the text-selection process, the user first has to type non-formatted text, then select it and only after that click the bold or italic button to format the text.

I want to, however, **provide the ability for the users to turn on either bold or italic buttons and then make all of the text formatting to be done as they type**.

I am currently using an iframe with the `.designMode` variable turned on. Currently, my implementation only supports text selection formatting, but I also want to implement realtime text formatting.

This is the html:

```
             <div id="textEditor">
                <div id="ribbon">
                    <button id="boldButton" title="Bold"><b>B</b></button>
                    <button id="italicButton" title="Italic"><em>I</em></button>
                </div>

                <div id="richTextArea">
                    <iframe id="wysiwyg" name="wysiwyg" frameborder="0"></iframe>
                </div>
            </div>
```

This is the corresponding script (javascript):

```
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
    var editor = wysiwyg.document; //wysiwyg iframe has name="wysiwyg"
    editor.designMode = "on";

    boldButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
        //when bold button is clicked, execCommand turns the text selection to bold
        editor.execCommand("Bold", false, null); 

    }, false);

    italicButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
        //when bold is clicked, bold the selected text
        editor.execCommand("Italic", false, null);
    }, false);
}, false);
```

Comment: Have you looked into `contentEditable` paragraphs?

Comment: Hello there! Yes, I have and have also chosen to implement a third-party library (https://mindmup.github.io/bootstrap-wysiwyg) that utilises such features.